# MySql count(*) super slow with concurrent queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a script that tries to read all the rows from a table like this:

```
select count(*) from table where col1 = 'Y' or col1 is null;
```

col1 and col2 are not indexed and this query usually takes ~20 seconds but if someone is already running this query, it takes ages and gets blocked.

We just have around 100k rows in the table and I tried it without the where clause and it causes the same issue.

The table uses InnoDB so, it doesn't store the exact count but I am curious if there is any concurrency parameter I should look into. I am not sure if absence of indexes on the table causes the issue but it doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If they are not indexed, then it is required to read the entire disk files of your tables to find your data. A single hard disk cannot perform very well concurrent read intensive operations. You have to index.

Comment: I looked into the disk read-write and they seem pretty flat. Does it mean that it is at the limit?

Comment: Did you try indexing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `SELECT COUNT(*)...` query is being serialized with other operations on your table. Unless you tell the MySQL server otherwise, your query will do its best to be very precise.

Try changing the [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html) [isolation level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) by issuing this command immediately before your query.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

Setting this enables so-called *dirty reads*, which means you might not count everything in the table that changes during your operation. But that probably will not foul up your application too badly.

(Adding appropriate indexes is always a good idea, but not the cause of the problem you ask about.)